# Pass Table Name as a Parameter in sql query using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate?

Tags: java, sql, jdbctemplate

I was executing a simple sql query ="

```
select id, first_name, last_name, city
from customer where id = :id
```

and using namedParamterJdbcTemplate to execute this query.

Now I want to make the table name also variable like this

```
select id, first_name, last_name, city
from :customer
where id = :id
```

I will Pass the table name and id using HashMap. 
But I am getting error stating invalid sql statement?

Comment: SQL does not allow you to pass in identifiers as parameters.  Identifiers include table names, column names, functions, database names, schema names, and operators.